# Does ribosome associated with RER separate from RER after finishing protein synthesis?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology

After ribosome associates with RER because of its specific signal sequence, and then when cotranslation translocation is finished, does ribosome return to free floating ribosome at cytosol? Or does it stay as combined condition?